# Why is it "what is that supposed to mean?" And not "...to means?"

Tags: infinitives, to-infinitive

I know it looks stupid but I really couldn't understand why it's "mean" and not "means". Is it because it's on the past?

Answer (score 1):

It's because it is in the [infinitive](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/infinitives/), which always uses the uninflected form.  Likewise:

- It is supposed to do that.
- It is not supposed to jump like that.
- It is supposed to mean nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is due to basic English infinitives.

- She has {to take} her medication.
- Not - She has to takes her medication.

- He is supposed {to attend} to his own wounds.
- Not - He is supposed to attends to his own wounds.

Infinitives are a basic feature of the English language, and many other languages including Hebrew. They should be among the first features to in which {to gain} expediency when learning English.